# How to open VMDK file

Tags: openbravo

I've downloaded the OpenbravoEFP zip file for windows from sourceforge. After extracting the file I've found two files `(i) openbravo-3-i386.vmx` and `(ii) openbravo-3-i386.vmdk`.
How can I install the software with these files ? Have I downloaded wrong files. I want to run the software in windows XP.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openbravo supports **VirtualBox appliance(.vmdk)** and **VMplayer appliance(.vmx)**

**Launch VMware appliance**

1. Install and Run VM Player.
2. Click on File -> Open Virtual Machine and select the vmx file you
   have uncompressed.
3. After boot you can login in the testing appliance

Click [here](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Installation/Appliance/Launch_appliance#Openbravo_Appliance_for_testing) for more information from openbravo wiki page

Answer (score 0):

VDMK are image files for a virtual machine, like VMware. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMDK

So you could use that image to run it on a simulated computer instance on your host machine and try it out there.